# Why are some questions in the question list faded?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Why is the question from TayE faded? (Is there a contribution he hasn't yet paid?)

This happens for several questions.

[image]

Is it my browser configuration?

Comment: Looks like one of the tags is set to be ignored.

Comment: @fooot: In my profile? [It seems not](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/3201).

Comment: I agree with @fooot's reading of the situation. Have you checked by mousing over the tags? is there one with a litthe red "x" next to the followers count?

Comment: you have jet-engine ignored: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/3201

Comment: Yes, I wasn't looking at the right place. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the first line hehehe